# Jenkins- How to format excluded SVN commit messages?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have Jenkins polling Subversion for changes, but I do not want a commit to trigger a build when the commit message is "Do not build". I have written "Do not build" in the Excluded Messages region, but commits with this message are still triggering. Is there some sort of formatting (i.e. quotes around the message) that I need for the exclusion to work?

Excluded Messages region in Jenkins: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgbab.jpg)

Commit Message I am using: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVgf0.jpg)

Comment: Please add exact copies of the commit message and of the `Excluded Messages` region.

Comment: @AlexO I have added images of each. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good... could you double-check that there's no additional blanks before or after the "Excluded Messages" entry?

Comment: @AlexO You're right, there was an extra space. Don't know how I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'll post this as an answer so you can accept it : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must not be any **extra space characters** before of after the entry in the "Excluded Messages" field. Otherwise, those characters will be part of the pattern, and they must be part of the commit messages as well then.